# Menu con una imagen de fondo

Tags: imagen, responsive

Buenos tardes pues estoy comenzando en el mundo del desarrollo y diseño web y estoy haciendo un menú con una imagen de fondo

- Quiero saber como los diseñadores o programadores le dicen
- Saben algún ejemplo para hacerlo responsivo como menú hamburguesa

Espero que me ayuden por favor les dejo el código por aquí y la pagina:

CODIGO:

https://github.com/manueldavid95/menu-imagen-fondo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1067/1280/720);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /*con este lo centras todo*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  transform: translateX(-100rem);
  animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
}

.brand span {
  color: crimson;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(100rem);
  animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav ul li a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; /*quita el margen de este ultimo elemento*/
}

nav ul li a::before,
nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: crimson;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: right;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after,
nav ul li a:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* animacion */
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {

  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Menu Responsive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <h1 class="brand"><a href="#"><span>M</span>anuel</a></h1>
        
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGINA:

https://manueldavid95.github.io/menu-imagen-fondo/

Comment: Por favor evita y agrega el código relevante a la pregunta aquí

Comment: gracias por la observación de verdad lo tomare en cuenta para próximas publicaciones por favor pudo ver el enlace a github pages por casualidad usted no tendrá algún menú de ejemplo o un sitio web donde elaboren uno similar ? usando flexbox ese codigo lo vi en un tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas hacer proyectos `responsive` deberás aprender algún `framework`; hacer todo desde cero en este mundo del desarrollo web resulta difícil a la larga, es por eso que te recomiendo que aprendas `bootstrap` en su versión mas reciente o `materialize`.

Pero si estas aquí mas por aprender podrías aplicar algo de `css` y `javascript`, aquí trate de adaptar tu proyecto para que sea `responsive`.

Disculpa por la sintaxis, no pude poner bien el código, tuve problemas para pegarlo.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1067/1280/720);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /*con este lo centras todo*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  transform: translateX(-100rem);
  animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
}

.brand span {
  color: crimson;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(100rem);
  animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav ul li a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; /*quita el margen de este ultimo elemento*/
}

nav ul li a::before,
nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: crimson;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: right;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after,
nav ul li a:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* animacion */
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {

  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <h1 class="brand"><a href="#"><span>M</span>anuel</a></h1>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: No considero adecuado que si ya estás incluyendo flexbox en tu maquetación, después acomodes múltiples elementos haciendolos flotantes

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder. Pero este tipo de menu tienen algún nombre ?. No me gusta usar float para la maquetacion me dan demasiados problemas. Por casualidad no tendrás algún ejemplo con flexbox ? o alguna pagina donde pueda encontrar un menú similar